# Is the [instruments] Tag too broad?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know if my thinking concurs with others here but the [instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments) tag seems a bit too broad and most questions would either have the instrument name in the title or body, (which would then proceed to require the relevant tag name for that instrument)

Or have an instrument name tag alongside it... which then makes the Instrument tag kind of redundant?

Just a thought should we axe it and emphasis more on individual instrument name tags, as opposed to a collective Tag?

Comment: It does seem kind of a meta-tag to me. I can't envision a question tagged "instrument", unless it was asking about instrumental music in contrast to say, vocal music. But that question would probably be too broad.

Comment: Currently it sees some use for specific instruments that only have 1 question about them, and thus cannot have their own tag.  In any cases where a more specific tag is also used (`brass`, `flute`, etc.) it should be removed.

Comment: There also now seems to be a rise in category tags for instruments such as Woodwinds... this may further reduce the need for the Instruments tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are a lot of questions that don't show it, I believe the tag can have a good use and that it is useful in certain scenarios.

I do think the tag definition should be altered because we have tags for most common instruments so the current tag definition is not useful. I would change the definition from:

> Questions about an instrument itself, rather than how to play it.

to:

> For questions about generalities about instruments or groups of instruments.

I've alway kind of been using it the second way as seen my question [Alternative ways to classify Instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16079/alternative-ways-to-classify-instruments) which is where that tag in my mind really fits. There are other questions that I can think of that would make use of this tag that have not been asked yet including:

- What instruments use the tenor clef?
- Is there a certain way to arrange instruments on a score?
- Why are bass instruments typically bigger in size then other instruments?

There's not really an appropriate tag to talk about each individual instrument in the proposed questions above and we're referring to instruments in groups that aren't very common so [instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments) would be very useful in those scenarios.

Comment: I see you thinking here yes that tag description seems more applicable. If more than one instrument fits into a certain category it may be helpful.